# Creating Docker image hierarchy with private registry

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

TL;DR **Must you put your private Docker URI in your Dockerfile `FROM` command if the parent image is in a private registry?**

I thought this should be an easily answerable question, but cannot find a good set of Google keywords...

Detail:

I have three repos, all built with separate CI calls; the order of these CI executions is correct for this DAG (i.e. parent image will be available when a child needs it):

- **Repo 1** holds a Dockerfile that constructs a base image with dependencies. It is slow moving
- **Repo 2 & 3** hold applications that are built in a Dockerfile that pulls `FROM` the image built in **Repo 1**. These change frequently.

As I understand it, if you don't specify a repo URI in your `FROM` command, docker assumes you are pulling from DockerHub. *Is this correct?*

If these images are stored in a private registry, is it true that the private registry must be explicitly included in the child Dockerfiles? *Is there another way?*

Answer (score 1):

Docker looks for the image name, on your local repository, if it does not find the image there, it would pull from the docker hub.

At first thought, it feels intuitive that we should be able to configure a private repository as the default, and then use it just as we would use docker hub.
However, this seems to be a topic of lengthy discussion, you can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11815#issuecomment-86732502).

Unfortunately, at the time of writing this, to build from a private repo, you will need to specify the complete URI in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<aws region>.amazonaws.com/<private image name>:latest
```

You will need to configure your Docker daemon to [authenticate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html) and pull from your private ECR repository:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
```

and then go for

```
docker build .
```

Alternatively, you can use arguments, to construct your ECR URI. This will keep things clean and parameterised in your Dockerfile while being explicit that you are using a private repo.
Eg:
In your `Dockerfile`

```
ARG PRIVATE_REPO
FROM ${PRIVATE_REPO}your_image_name
```

And build the docker image with:

```
docker build . --build-arg PRIVATE_REPO=aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic assumptions are correct: if your base image is in a private registry, you generally must include the registry name in downstream Dockerfiles' `FROM` lines, `docker run` commands, Compose and Kubernetes `image:` lines, and so on. If the registry part of the image name is absent, it defaults to `docker.io`.

```sh
# Expands to docker.io/library/alpine:latest
FROM alpine
```

This only actually matters if the image isn't already present on the local machine, in which case Docker will automatically pull it.  If it's already present, Docker doesn't worry about where it came from and just uses it as-is.  If you have a manual multi-stage build, but don't actually push any of the intermediate stages anywhere, it doesn't actually matter if you tag it for any particular repository.

```sh
# "step 2" Dockerfile
# Build with: `docker build -t step2 -f step2.Dockerfile .`
# Starts from image in internal repository
FROM registry.example.com/img/step1
```

```sh
# Application Dockerfile
# Depends on "step 2" image being built first
# Since we expect step2:latest image to be present locally, won't pull
FROM step2
```